# Where do I call mnesia:create_schema/1 in a relx release?

Tags: erlang, mnesia, rebar3, relx

I have an OTP application 'myapp' which depends on mnesia. Where should I put the call to `mnesia:create_schema/1`?

If I add the dependency to `{applications,[]}` in myapp.app.src, mnesia starts first and I can't call create_schema in `myapp:start/2`. It might make sense to call it in myapp.script/myapp.boot, but relx doesn't let me add anything to that.

I don't want to make mnesia an included application.

EDIT: I've found a workaround by listing mnesia in the applications in the relx config, but running `mnesia:create_schema([node()]), application:ensure_all_started(mnesia, permanent)`  in `myapp:start/2`. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too. You should include `{mnesia, load}` in relx app list, create schema in `start/2` callback of your application and start mnesia. It's good to write `{mnesia, [{dir, "YourMnesiaDBPath"}]}` in `sys.config` too.